# Http Artifact binding for saml 2.0 in spring security 6

Tags: spring-security-saml2

Previously we were using aritifact binding using spring-security-saml2-core.How can we do it in  spring-security-saml2-service-provider

```
@Autowired
    private VelocityEngine velocityEngine;
    
    @Bean(initMethod = "initialize")
    public StaticBasicParserPool parserPool() {
        return new StaticBasicParserPool();
    }
    
    
    private ArtifactResolutionProfile artifactResolutionProfile() {
        final ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl artifactResolutionProfile = new ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl(httpClient());
        artifactResolutionProfile.setProcessor(new SAMLProcessorImpl(soapBinding()));
        return artifactResolutionProfile;
    }

    @Bean
    public HTTPArtifactBinding artifactBinding(ParserPool parserPool, VelocityEngine velocityEngine) {
        return new HTTPArtifactBinding(parserPool, velocityEngine, artifactResolutionProfile());
    }

    @Bean
    public HTTPSOAP11Binding soapBinding() {
        return new HTTPSOAP11Binding(parserPool());
    }

    @Bean
    public HTTPPostBinding httpPostBinding() {
        return new HTTPPostBinding(parserPool(), velocityEngine);
    }

    @Bean
    public HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding httpRedirectDeflateBinding() {
        return new HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding(parserPool());
    }

    @Bean
    public HTTPSOAP11Binding httpSOAP11Binding() {
        return new HTTPSOAP11Binding(parserPool());
    }

    @Bean
    public HTTPPAOS11Binding httpPAOS11Binding() {
        return new HTTPPAOS11Binding(parserPool());
    }
```

Tried to go through the documentation. if anyone have please share